backend url is given as undefined
Server Error
TypeError: Failed to parse URL from undefined/store/regions
This error happened while generating the page. Any console logs will be displayed in the terminal window.
Source
src\middleware.ts (21:30) @ fetch
19 | ) {
20 |   // Fetch regions from Medusa. We can't use the JS client here because middleware is running on Edge and the client needs a Node environment.

21 |   const { regions } = await fetch(${BACKEND_URL}/store/regions, {
|                            ^
22 |     next: {
23 |       revalidate: 3600,
24 |       tags: ["regions"]

backend url is not fetching in the from nextjs storefront to medusa backend

Have you added BACKEND_URL in your .env file?

In my case, the problem was that I used default value for env variable NEXT_PUBLIC_MEDUSA_BACKEND_URL in my project (.env.local).
But because I started using docker and created separate containers for each service: db, backend, storefront, redis I had to adjust this variable.
So I added this in my docker-compose.yaml file
environment:
  NEXT_PUBLIC_MEDUSA_BACKEND_URL: http://backend:9000

Where 'backend' is the name of my backend service (medusa backend)
Here is the whole working docker-compose.yaml file that I use for my first medusa project
services:
 db:
  image: postgres:14-alpine
  container_name: db
  environment:
    POSTGRES_USER: medusa_user
    POSTGRES_PASSWORD: medusa_password
    POSTGRES_DB: medusa_db
  volumes:
    - ./data/postgres:/var/lib/postgresql/data
  ports:
    - "5432:5432"
  networks:
    - medusa-network
 backend:
  build:
    context: ./medusa
    dockerfile: Dockerfile
  working_dir: /medusa
  volumes:
    - ./medusa:/medusa:rw
  environment:
    DATABASE_URL: postgres://medusa_user:medusa_password@db:5432/medusa-medusa
    REDIS_URL: redis://redis:6379
    JWT_SECRET: your_jwt_secret
    COOKIE_SECRET: your_cookie_secret
  depends_on:
    - db
    - redis
  ports:
    - "9000:9000"
  networks:
    - medusa-network
storefront:
  build:
    context: ./medusa-storefront
    dockerfile: Dockerfile
  working_dir: /app
  volumes:
    - ./medusa-storefront:/app:rw
  environment:
    NEXT_PUBLIC_MEDUSA_BACKEND_URL: http://backend:9000
  depends_on:
    - backend
  ports:
    - "8000:8000"
  networks:
    - medusa-network
redis:
  image: redis:6-alpine
  container_name: redis
  ports:
    - "6379:6379"
  networks:
    - medusa-network
networks:
 medusa-network:
  driver: bridge

Hope my answer will help someone)

if you have already created the BACKEND_URL in your .env file you need run npm dev in back and front at the same time

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

Try to restart the server multiple times if needed. It will work eventually.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
